# Android Float.parseFloat results in a fatal error due to decimal point

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to parse a float from a string:

```
 EditText CurrPLC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CurrPLC);
 String s5 = CurrPLC.getText().toString();
 float F5 = Float.parseFloat(s5);
```

This works great until I try to write a negative value into the `EditText`. Because the "negative" symbol is on the same button as the decimal point, I write a decimal first and then the app crashes because a string of "." cannot be parsed into a float value. The code is executed on any text change in the `EditText`

Here's the `EditText` code from the layout file:

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/CurrPLC"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:hint="eg. 3277"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:digits="-0123456789."
            android:inputType="numberSigned|numberDecimal"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:background="@drawable/plc_edit_text_holo_light"
            android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/CurrPLCLabel"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CurrPLCLabel"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        />
```

Is there something I've done wrong, or is this simply down to handling this before the error occurs?

Thanks

Comment: At what point are you parsing the float? Are you using a `TextWatcher` or on press of a button?  I don't follow what you mean by `the "negative" symbol is on the same button as the decimal point`

Comment: @AbtinGramian Yes i'm using a `TextWatcher` so it's updating everytime a key is pressed. To put a "negative" symbol (-), its on the same button as a decimal point, you have to press the decimal point button twice. It's just the standard android numeric keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment of using a `TextWatcher` which would attempt to parse the float on each key press, the problem is not with negative numbers.

`parseFloat()` will work fine with negative numbers.  The problem is with an empty string or `-`, `-.`, or `.` most likely.

So you should not parse on each key press and instead only do it wherever you need it (I'm not sure of your full use case so I can't comment on the appropriate time and place to parse the float).  Otherwise you need to add a `try`/`catch` for `java.lang.NumberFormatException` wherever you are currently parsing the float.